# How to update column while selecting row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a videos table.

I want to select a row in table at the same time i want to update views(+1) column in same row.

Is here anything possible in a single query?

Comment: you wanna do this in a sql query ?

Comment: Make a stored procedure that returns your select set, but first updates the view count.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll have to do that with two queries.

Answer (score 1):

how single the queryis?
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE id=1 ;update `test_table` set test_col=test_col+1 where id=1;

Answer (score 1):

If You want to do this in a query , you can create trigger on SELECT Like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGER NAME] AFTER SELECT ON [TABLE NAME]
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE [TABLE NAME] SET [ FIELD ] = [ FIELD ] + 1 WHERE ...... ;
END;
```

Each time you select from your table , foreach result that matched by your where clause result fields will update

Comment: I want particular time select only.so i can't use TRIGGER

Comment: Oops!I think you should use two queries!There is no way to do that!

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL supports `UPDATE ... RETURNING`, which would do what you want, but I don't believe MySQL can do this.  You will need to do two queries.